# Fitting canvas in parent div

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, window, particles

I am trying to make my canvas fit inside a div.

```
    // Make the Canvas Responsive

    window.onload = function(){
      wih = window.innerHeight;
      wiw = window.innerWidth;
    }
    window.onresize = function(){
      wih = window.innerHeight;
      wiw = window.innerWidth;
    }

    // Define the min and max Values for the Randomize Function.
    radiusMin = 1;
    radiusMax = 40;
    tubeMin = 1;
    tubeMax = 40;
    radialSegmentsMin = 1;
    radialSegmentsMax = 800;
    tubularSegmentsMin = 1;
    tubularSegmentsMax = 30;
    pMin = 1;
    pMax = 20;
    qMin = 1;
    qMax = 20;
    heightScaleMin = 0;
    heightScaleMax = 5;


    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        45, // fov (45 / 60)
        window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, // wiw / wih,
        0.1,
        1000
    );

    // Create a WebGLRenderer
    var webGLRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    webGLRenderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0x000000, 1.0));
    webGLRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    webGLRenderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;

    // Append the output of the renderer to the html element
    document.getElementById("WebGL-output").append(webGLRenderer.domElement);
    var step = 0;
    var knot;

    // Keep Aspect Ratio on Resize
    window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize, false);
    function onWindowResize() {
      camera.aspect = wiw / wih;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      webGLRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    }

    // Position and point the camera to the center of the scene
    camera.position.x = -30;
    camera.position.y = -40;
    camera.position.z = 50;
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(10, 0, 0));
    var clock = new THREE.Clock();
    var trackballControls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, webGLRenderer.domElement);
    trackballControls.rotateSpeed = 4.0;
    trackballControls.zoomSpeed = 1.0;
    trackballControls.panSpeed = 1.0;
    trackballControls.noZoom = false;
    trackballControls.noPan = true;
    trackballControls.staticMoving = false;
    trackballControls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;

    // Setup Controls for dat.GUI
    var controls = new function() {
      // Default Values
      this.color = "#7a4d0c";
      this.radius = 22;
      this.tube = 32;
      this.radialSegments = 800;
      this.tubularSegments = 12;
      this.p = 10; // wind p times around its axis of rotational symmetry
      this.q = 14; // wind q times around a circle in the interior of the torus
      this.heightScale = 2;
      this.asParticles = true;
      this.rotate = true;
      this.animate = false; // Animates radialSegments
      this.randomize = false; // Randomize Mesh

      this.redraw = function() {
        // Remove the old plane
        if (knot) scene.remove(knot);
        // Create a new one
        var geom = new THREE.TorusKnotGeometry(
            controls.radius,
            controls.tube,
            Math.round(controls.radialSegments),
            Math.round(controls.tubularSegments),
            Math.round(controls.p),
            Math.round(controls.q),
            controls.heightScale,
            controls.color
        );

        if (controls.asParticles) {
          knot = createParticleSystem(geom);
        } else {
          knot = createMesh(geom);
        }
        // Add it to the scene.
        scene.add(knot);
      };
    }();

    var gui = new dat.GUI({
      resizable : false
    });
    gui.addColor(controls, "color").onChange(controls.redraw);
    gui.add(controls, "radius", radiusMin, radiusMax).onChange(controls.redraw);
    gui.add(controls, "tube", tubeMin, tubeMax).onChange(controls.redraw);
    gui.add(controls, "radialSegments", radialSegmentsMin, radialSegmentsMax).step(1).onChange(controls.redraw);
    gui.add(controls, "tubularSegments", tubularSegmentsMin, tubularSegmentsMax).step(1).onChange(controls.redraw);
    gui.add(controls, "p", pMin, pMax).step(1).onChange(controls.redraw);
    gui.add(controls, "q", qMin, qMax).step(1).onChange(controls.redraw);
    gui.add(controls, "heightScale", heightScaleMin, heightScaleMax).onChange(controls.redraw);
    gui.add(controls, "asParticles").onChange(controls.redraw);
    gui.add(controls, "rotate").onChange(controls.redraw);
    gui.add(controls, "animate").onChange(controls.redraw);
    gui.add(controls, "randomize").onChange(controls.redraw);

    gui.close();
    controls.redraw();

    render();

    // From THREE.js examples
    // Create Sprites for the particleSystem
    function generateSprite() {
      var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      canvas.width = 16;
      canvas.height = 16;

      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      var gradient = context.createRadialGradient(
          canvas.width / 2,
          canvas.height / 2,
          0,
          canvas.width / 2,
          canvas.height / 2,
          canvas.width / 2
      );
      gradient.addColorStop(0.0, controls.color);
      gradient.addColorStop(0.2, controls.color);
      gradient.addColorStop(0.4, controls.color);
      gradient.addColorStop(1.0, "rgba(0,0,0,1)");

      context.fillStyle = gradient;
      context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

     var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
      texture.needsUpdate = true;
      return texture;
    }

    // Create a particleSystem and use the Sprites
    function createParticleSystem(geom) {
      var material = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff,
        size: 2,
        transparent: true,
        blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending, // Time to Shine!
        map: generateSprite()
      });

      var system = new THREE.ParticleSystem(geom, material);
      system.sortParticles = true;
      return system;
      }
```

Currently, it wants to take over the full width because I edited this with CSS and would only accept an "Important" tag. The div is 50vw in tablets and desktops, but 100vw on mobile. The problem is during mobile the canvas wants to ignore the @media style that tells it to resize to 100vw;;;; If this stupid canvas would just stick to the width of the div, it would work.

I am still a very big beginner in Javascript, so any explaination is extremely welcomed.

The canvas needs to fit within the DIV so when the layout responds to mobile, it will behave properly.

Comment: have you tried lowering the on load size? maybe make that smaller?

Comment: window.onload = function(){
      wih = window.innerHeight;
      wiw = window.innerWidth;
    }

Should I replace inner with client?

Comment: try dividing by two on each window.innerHeight/2 ; window.innerWidth/2

Comment: I just tried, but no avail. BLEH

Comment: You might find [this article useful](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-responsive.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will work for you and your situation but no harm in trying...

The key is window.matchMedia. This is passed a media query string identical to those used in CSS media queries:

```
const mq = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 500px)" );

if (mq.matches) {
// window width is at least 500px
} else {
// window width is less than 500px
}
```

You can also add an event listener which fires when a change is detected:

```
// media query event handler
if (matchMedia) {
const mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 500px)");
mq.addListener(WidthChange);
WidthChange(mq);
}

// media query change
function WidthChange(mq) {
if (mq.matches) {
// window width is at least 500px
} else {
// window width is less than 500px
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the renderer to respect the width & height of the container div, you need to check the width and height of that container div, not of the entire window:

```
// Save reference of the parentDiv to be used later
var parent = document.getElementById('parentDiv');
parent.append(webGLRenderer.domElement);

// When window is resized
resizeRenderer() {
    // Get width & height of parentDiv
    var width = parent.clientWidth;
    var height = parent.clientHeight;
    webGLRenderer.setSize(width, height);
}

// Add window resize listener
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeRenderer);

// Force renderer resizing once
resizeRenderer();
```

This way, it'll respect whatever media queries you have established for the `parentDiv` in CSS.